# Firebase Analytics is showing inaccurate data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

My app requires users to register in order to use the app. The app has 50 registered users. Google Play Developer Console shows installs on ~43 active devices.
Firebase Analytics shows ~6 Daily Active Users, ~100 Weekly Active Users and ~300 Monthly Active Users.

My testing device could be getting counted various times as the debug build is installed and uninstalled various times. However, I doubt the number can bloat up the WAU and MAU to such large numbers.

If the 50 registered users open the app for a combined 100 times, Firebase should still count them as 50 WAUs, right? If one unique user opens the app (fires screen_view) 10 times, it will still be counted as one active user, right?

How can the app have 100 weekly active users if the total number of users who registered is 50? Am I intepreting the data wrong or is there something wrong with the way the analytics is setup?

Comment: How many downloads/installs and uninstalls does Google Play show you in the period of the last 30 days?
My guess here is that 300 users (in the last months) registered but the majority never came back or even uninstalled the app.

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Did you find the source of the problem?